# Android: How to display welcome name in all activities

Tags: java, android

I am able to display welcome name after register activity, but I am wondering how to display welcome name in all the activities.

Comment: please write clearly what you want. What is the mean for welcome name

Comment: Could you display any text in all activities ? Than you can display the "welcome name" using the way. :) Sorry, but your question doesn't direct us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Store that name in [SharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and use it whenever its needed.

Initialize Preference object

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Store values in it

```
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("name", "name user have entered");
editor.commit();
```

Get stored value

```
sharedpreferences.getString("name", "default value");
```

Comment: Thank you @RRR. I did that your answer was very helpful.